# Elasticsearch tailor to user preferences

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I would like to know if there is a way to search in Elasticsearch based upon a user's preferences. Basically, we know a number of tags that a user likes (and how many times they liked that tag so it has a weight to it). The posts in the index have tags attached to them. We like to rank posts search results based upon the tags that they like!

Any course of action on how to accomplish this? Another Index? Child? New to Elasticsearch and I love it already.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [function score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) or [custom filters score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-custom-filters-score-query.html) to boost results based on the tags that each user has. You will need to wrap user's request into functions score query or custom filters score query with a filter for each tag. The boost of each filter will depend on the number of times this tag was liked by the user.